# Trying to create a rollover / active state for Nivo Slider thumbnails

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, nivo-slider

I'm using a Nivo Slider in Wordpress that I've got working perfectly except that I need a div or img to overlay the thumbnails using jQuery.

I can't upload files since this is my first post, but here is an image of the gallery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVKmL.png

I have hover states working everywhere else on my site using a class div over the thumbnail and with this code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bottomRowLook li a').hover(
          function(){
               jQuery(this).children('.lookbook-lower-overlay').show();
          }, //hover in
          function(){
               jQuery(this).children('.lookbook-lower-overlay').hide();
          } //hover out
     ); 
});
```

This isn't working for the Nivo Slider since it's automatically generating thumbnails and I can't pinpoint where my code goes in. I tried using appendTo but I'm not very good at jQuery and mostly just go by tutorials I find on the internet.

The loop that is generating the thumbnails + main image looks like this:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider default-theme">
                        <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => 15, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); ?>
                        <?php $attachments = get_posts( $args ); ?>
                        <?php if ( $attachments ): ?>
                            <?php foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ): ?>   
                                <div class="look-upper-overlay"></div>  
                                <?php $full = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, true ); ?>
                                <?php $rel = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', true); ?>
                                <?php $title = $attachment->post_title; ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $full[0]; ?>" data-thumb="<?php echo $rel[0]; ?>" title="<?php echo $title ?>" />';
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the markup of the generated thumbnails?

Comment: How about also posting the HTML that it outputs from that PHP you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of jQuery code and let me know if it makes a difference in your specific scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bottomRowLook li a').on('hover', function(){
      $(this).children('.lookbook-lower-overlay').show();
    },
    function(){
      $(this).children('.lookbook-lower-overlay').hide();
    }
  ); 
});
```

This might be related to the way that Nivo creates the thumbnails on the fly. It might not be accessible in the DOM yet. The `.on` event should help out in these kind of situations.

It's hard to determine without a working example, but hope that works for you.